# How can I save an Inkscape png with a transparent background?

Tags: inkscape, transparency, png

Whenever I save my Inkscape drawing as `.png` (`save as -> cairopng`), even if there is nothing behind my drawing, it saves it with a background, like this:

[image]

How can I save with a transparent background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just using `save as -> png` does not apply the transparent background. However, the transparent background is the default when you export:

`File -> Export Bitmap -> Export`

Make sure to set the file extention to `.png`. I chose it to only export the page so it doesn't include any of the rubbish off to the side that I don't want included in my file. Drawing exports everything in the file.

[image]

If you want the background colour to be anything different, you can open the `Document Properties` dialog, and click the Background colour selector:

[image]

And when you have exported you will have your image with the background:

Transparent:

[image]